# How to make a data frame/tibble from two vectors with unequal size

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two vectors:

```
a <- c("HMSC-ad", "HMSC-bm", "HMSC-he")
b <- c("distal", "proximal")
```

What I want to do is to create the following tibble/data frame:

```
  a      b 
HMSC-ad distal
HMSC-bm distal
HMSC-he distal
HMSC-ad proximal
HMSC-bm proximal
HMSC-he proximal
```

I tried this but fail:

```
 > library(tidyverse)
 > as.tibble(list(a=a,b=b) )

 Error: Column `b` must be length 1 or 6, not 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `expand.grid`:

```
a <- c("HMSC-ad", "HMSC-bm", "HMSC-he")
b <- c("distal", "proximal")

df1 <- expand.grid(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try CJ(a, b) from the data.table package.

```
library(data.table)
CJ(a=a, b=b)
```

The CJ stands for "cross-join" which I believe is what you're after.